# Ajax call not saving form information

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have tried using the code below to save and display information using ajax. But it doesn't work.

Here's the code.

```
<?php session_start();?>
<html>
<head>
<script src="style/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="style/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> 

<script>
$(function() {
$("#ajaxquery").live( "submit" , function(){
    // Intercept the form submission
    var formdata = $(this).serialize(); // Serialize all form data

    // Post data to your PHP processing script
    $.post( "show.php", formdata, function( data ) {
        // Act upon the data returned, setting it to #success <div>
        $("#success").html ( data );
    });

    return false; // Prevent the form from actually submitting
})
});
</script>

</head>

<form id="ajaxquery" method="post" action="">
<label for="field">Type Something:</label>
<input type="text" name="field" id="field" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="Send to AJAX" />
</form>

<div id="success"> </div>
</html>
```

AND MY *show.php* which displays data in id="success"

```
<?php
// Process form data
echo '<strong>You submitted to me:</strong><br/>';
print_r( $_REQUEST );

?>
```

Please help...

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated. use `.on()` instead.

Comment: Do you get any error messages? Have you checked your Console in your browser to confirm the ajax request is being sent correctly?

Comment: @developerwjk his form is `$(this)` - he is using it inside the event-handler for the form-selector `$("#ajaxquery")`

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? Try debugging using firebug or chrome developer tools.

Comment: You should include jQuery UI *after* jQuery. I'd do that first before checking your error console again - there will be a number of errors just due to that.

Comment: Check out [How to open the JavaScript console in different browsers?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) if you're not sure where we're all asking you to look.

Answer (score 0):

at first you have to load jquery ui after jquery

```
<script src="style/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="style/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

then in this case you don't need to use live you can simply do this

```
$("#ajaxquery").submit(function(){
    // your code
})
```

"live" function ( or for now "on" ) used when you going to create or load html code after you set events.